# jQuery is Undefined as soon as .net solution is run

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010

VS 2010, C#, MVC 3, jQuery 1.8.1.8. Project compiles fine on another developer machine, and I'm trying to set up mine to work.

On Run, I get an error message "Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'jQuery' is undefined"

it fails on a jQuery UI Widget function 1.8.18:

```
*/(function(a,b){function d(b){return!a(b).parents().andSelf().filter(function(){return a.curCSS(this,"visibility")==="hidden"||a.expr.filters.hidden(this)}).length}function c(b,c){var e=b.nodeName.toLowerCase();if("area"===e){var f=b.parentNode,g=f.name,h;if(!b.href||!g||f.nodeName.toLowerCase()!=="map")return!1;h=a("img[usemap=#"+g+"]")[0];return!!h&&d(h)}return(/input|select|textarea|button|object/.test(e)?!b.disabled:"a"==e?b.href||c:c)&&d(b)}a.ui=a.ui||{};a.ui.version||(a.extend(a.ui,{version:"1.8.18",keyCode:{ALT:18,BACKSPACE:8,CAPS_LOCK:20,COMMA:188,COMMAND:91,COMMAND_LEFT:91,COMMAND_RIGHT:93,CONTROL:17,DELETE:46,DOWN:40,END:35,ENTER:13,ESCAPE:27,HOME:36,INSERT:45,LEFT:37,MENU:93,NUMPAD_ADD:107,NUMPAD_DECIMAL:110,NUMPAD_DIVIDE:111,NUMPAD_ENTER:108,NUMPAD_MULTIPLY:106,NUMPAD_SUBTRACT:109,PAGE_DOWN:34,PAGE_UP:33,PERIOD:190,RIGHT:39,SHIFT:16,SPACE:32,TAB:9,UP:38,WINDOWS:91}}),a.fn.extend({propAttr:a.fn.prop||a.fn.attr,_focus:a.fn.focus,focus:function(b,c){return typeof b=="number"?this.each(function(){var d=this;setTimeout(function(){a(d).focus(),c&&c.call(d)},b)}):this._focus.apply(this,arguments)},scrollParent:function(){var b;a.browser.msie&&/(static|relative)/.test(this.css("position"))||/absolute/.test(this.css("position"))?b=this.parents().filter(function(){return/(relative|absolute|fixed)/.test(a.curCSS(this,"position",1))&&/(auto|scroll)/.test(a.curCSS(this,"overflow",1)+a.curCSS(this,"overflow-y",1)+a.curCSS(this,"overflow-x",1))}).eq(0):b=this.parents().filter(function(){return/(auto|scroll)/.test(a.curCSS(this,"overflow",1)+a.curCSS(this,"overflow-y",1)+a.curCSS(this,"overflow-x",1))}).eq(0);return/fixed/.test(this.css("position"))||!b.length?a(document):b},zIndex:function(c){if(c!==b)return this.css("zIndex",c);if(this.length){var d=a(this[0]),e,f;while(d.length&&d[0]!==document){e=d.css("position");if(e==="absolute"||e==="relative"||e==="fixed"){f=parseInt(d.css("zIndex"),10);if(!isNaN(f)&&f!==0)return f}d=d.parent()}}return 0},disableSelection:function(){return this.bind((a.support.selectstart?"selectstart":"mousedown")+".ui-disableSelection",function(a){a.preventDefault()})},enableSelection:function(){return this.unbind(".ui-disableSelection")}}),a.each(["Width","Height"],function(c,d){function h(b,c,d,f){a.each(e,function(){c-=parseFloat(a.curCSS(b,"padding"+this,!0))||0,d&&(c-=parseFloat(a.curCSS(b,"border"+this+"Width",!0))||0),f&&(c-=parseFloat(a.curCSS(b,"margin"+this,!0))||0)});return c}var e=d==="Width"?["Left","Right"]:["Top","Bottom"],f=d.toLowerCase(),g={innerWidth:a.fn.innerWidth,innerHeight:a.fn.innerHeight,outerWidth:a.fn.outerWidth,outerHeight:a.fn.outerHeight};a.fn["inner"+d]=function(c){if(c===b)return g["inner"+d].call(this);return this.each(function(){a(this).css(f,h(this,c)+"px")})},a.fn["outer"+d]=function(b,c){if(typeof b!="number")return g["outer"+d].call(this,b);return this.each(function(){a(this).css(f,h(this,b,!0,c)+"px")})}}),a.extend(a.expr[":"],{data:function(b,c,d){return!!a.data(b,d[3])},focusable:function(b){return c(b,!isNaN(a.attr(b,"tabindex")))},tabbable:function(b){var d=a.attr(b,"tabindex"),e=isNaN(d);return(e||d>=0)&&c(b,!e)}}),a(function(){var b=document.body,c=b.appendChild(c=document.createElement("div"));c.offsetHeight,a.extend(c.style,{minHeight:"100px",height:"auto",padding:0,borderWidth:0}),a.support.minHeight=c.offsetHeight===100,a.support.selectstart="onselectstart"in c,b.removeChild(c).style.display="none"}),a.extend(a.ui,{plugin:{add:function(b,c,d){var e=a.ui[b].prototype;for(var f in d)e.plugins[f]=e.plugins[f]||[],e.plugins[f].push([c,d[f]])},call:function(a,b,c){var d=a.plugins[b];if(!!d&&!!a.element[0].parentNode)for(var e=0;e<d.length;e++)a.options[d[e][0]]&&d[e][1].apply(a.element,c)}},contains:function(a,b){return document.compareDocumentPosition?a.compareDocumentPosition(b)&16:a!==b&&a.contains(b)},hasScroll:function(b,c){if(a(b).css("overflow")==="hidden")return!1;var d=c&&c==="left"?"scrollLeft":"scrollTop",e=!1;if(b[d]>0)return!0;b[d]=1,e=b[d]>0,b[d]=0;return e},isOverAxis:function(a,b,c){return a>b&&a<b+c},isOver:function(b,c,d,e,f,g){return a.ui.isOverAxis(b,d,f)&&a.ui.isOverAxis(c,e,g)}}))})(jQuery);/*!
```

Upgrading using NuGet does nothing, and I'm limited as to what I can upgrade to, based on the other developers not being able to upgrade.

I've compared my solution to the other developer's and they both look the same. He's not using anything of NuGet either.

Anyone have any hints?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title | Compliance</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.png" /> 

    <script type="text/javascript">
        left_width = 163;
    </script>

    @Html.CssFile("common.css")
    @Html.CssFile("MedResearchPrint.css", true, "print")  
    @Html.CssFile("style.css", false) 
    @Html.CssFile("sorting/dataTable.css") 
    @Html.CssFile("menus/single_seventeen.css")
    @Html.CssFile("galleriffic-5.css")

    @Html.CssFile("jquery.autocomplete.css")
    @Html.CssFile("fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.0.css")
    <link href="@GlobalVariables.ResourceDomain/javascript/msgbox/jquery.msgbox.css"     rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    @Html.CssFile("jqueryui/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.css")
    <link href="@GlobalVariables.ResourceDomain/javascript/windows/dhtmlxwindows.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@GlobalVariables.ResourceDomain/javascript/windows/skins/dhtmlxwindows_dhx_skyblue.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    @Html.ScriptFile("jquery-1.5.1.min.js")   
    @Html.ScriptFile("form/jquery.form.js")  
    @Html.ScriptFile("jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js", false)
    @Html.ScriptFile("fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.0.pack.js")
    @Html.ScriptFile("MedResearch.js")    
    @Html.ScriptFile("menu.js")     
    @Html.ScriptFile("effects.core.js")     
    @Html.ScriptFile("jquery.corners.js")     
    @Html.ScriptFile("jquery.cookie.js")     
    @Html.ScriptFile("effects.slide.js")    


    @Html.ScriptFile("sorting/jquery.dataTables.min.js") 
    @Html.ScriptFile("shortcut/shortcut.js")

    @Html.ScriptFile("jquery.galleriffic.js") 
    @Html.ScriptFile("jquery.opacityrollover.js")
    <script src="@GlobalVariables.ResourceDomain/javascript/msgbox/jquery.msgbox.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    @Html.ScriptFile("hash/hash.js")
    @Html.ScriptFile("time/jquery.ui.timepicker.js", false)
    @Html.ScriptFile("numeric/jquery.numeric.pack.js", false)

    <script src="@GlobalVariables.ResourceDomain/javascript/windows/dhtmlxcommon.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@GlobalVariables.ResourceDomain/javascript/windows/dhtmlxwindows.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@GlobalVariables.ResourceDomain/javascript/windows/dhtmlxcontainer.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/")content/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/")content/js/jquery-ui1.8.18.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@GlobalVariables.ResourceDomain/javascript/windows/lib.js"></script>-->
    <script type="text/javascript">root = "@Url.Content("~/")";</script>
    <script src="@GlobalVariables.ResourceDomain/javascript/windows/lib.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    @Html.ScriptFile("common.js", false) 
    @RenderSection("Head", false)

    <!--[if lt IE 8]>
    @Html.CssFile("MedResearchIE.css")
    @Html.CssFile("IE7Fixes.css", false)

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            if($(".header .filter").val() != null)
                $(".header").addClass("left");
        });
    </script>
    <![endif]-->


</head>
<body class="thrColLiqHdr" onload="fixHeight();">
    <div id="vp_container">
    <a id="top"></a>
    <div id="container0">
        <div id="container">
            <div id="masthead" style="background-image: url('@ViewBag.ImageFile');">
                <div id="siteName">
                    <img src="@GlobalVariables.ResourceDomain/images/iresearch.png" alt="iResearch" />
                </div>

                <div id="icons">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="toggle_lpanel" class="menu_collapse_left" title="Hide Left Panel">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="toggle_rpanel" class="menu_collapse_right" title="Hide Right Panel">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>&nbsp;&nbsp; 
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="toggle_bpanels" class="hide_both" title="Hide Both Panels">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>&nbsp;&nbsp; 
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:print();" title="Print">
                        <img src="@GlobalVariables.ResourceDomain/images/silkIcons/printer.png" alt="print" />
                    </a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                </div>
                <div id="about_img">
                    <a href="#" id="image_src" data-number="@ViewBag.ImageNumber" title="Learn more about this image">@ViewBag.ImageDesc</a>
                </div>

            <div id="globalNav">
                <div id="globalNav_item1" class="globalNav_item">
                    <a href="http://gradstudies.med.miami.edu" class="glink">Graduate Studies<br />
                    </a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="globalNav_item2" class="globalNav_item">
                    <a href="https://research.miami.edu" class="glink">Research Reporting</a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="globalNav_item3" class="globalNav_item_current">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="glink">Compliance</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="utility">
                    @if(GlobalVariables.User != null) 
                    {
                        <text><a href="@Url.Action("logoutcas", "account")" id="sign_out" title="Sign Out">Sign Out</a> |     <span id="active_username">@GlobalVariables.User.ToString()</span> <span id="record_role"></span></text>

                        <input type="hidden" id="user_role" value="@GlobalVariables.User.Role.Code" />
                    }
                </div>
                <div id="globalNav_b">
                </div>
                <!-- end #header -->
            </div>

            @if (IsSectionDefined("Left"))
            {
                @RenderSection("Left", false)
            }
            else
            {
                if (ViewBag.MenuGroups != null)
                {
                    <div id="colleft">
                        <div id="panel">
                            @if (GlobalVariables.User != null)
                         {
                                <div id="sidebar1">
                                    <ul id="main-nav">
                                        @foreach (var item in ((List<UMiami.Core.MenuGroup>)ViewBag.MenuGroups).OrderBy(p => p.OrderNumber))
                                        {
                                            <li><a class="nav-top-item @(item.IsSelected ? " current" : "")"  href="@(item.LinkUrl != null ? item.LinkUrl : "#")">@item.Name</a>
                                                @if (item.WebPages.Count > 0)
                                                {
                                                    <ul>
                                                        @foreach (var page in item.WebPages.OrderBy(p => p.OrderNumber))
                                                        {
                                                            <li><a title="@page.Description" href="@page.LinkUrl" class="@(page.IsSelected ? "current" : "")">@page.Name</a></li>
                                                        }
                                                    </ul>
                                                }
                                            </li>
                                        }
                                        @RenderSection("AdditionalMenuItems", false)

                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                         }
                        </div>
                    </div>
                }
            }

           <div class="wrapper">
            @if (IsSectionDefined("Right"))
            {
                <div id="colright">
                    <div id="panelright">
                        <div id="sidebar2">
                            <div class="content">
                                @RenderSection("Right")
                                <div class="cleaner margin">&nbsp;</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                 </div>
            }


                <div id="mainContent" class="mainContent">
                    @RenderBody()

                    <div id="loading" style="display: none;"><img alt="loading..." src="@Url.Content("~/content/img/ajax-loading.gif")" /></div>
                    <form action="/" id="excel_form" method="post"></form>

                    <iframe id="hidden-iframe" style="display:none;"></iframe>
                 </div>

                <div class="cleaner">&nbsp;</div>

                <div id="footer">
                    <p>
                    Sponsored.
                    </p>
                    <div id="anchor">
                       <a href="#" title="Return to Top">
                            <img src="@GlobalVariables.ResourceDomain/images/return_btns.gif" alt="top" /></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is likely that jQuery isn't being loaded correctly in the environment with the error. Inspect to make sure there is no 404 and the script load order is correct (both of these can be checked from the "Network" area of browser developer tools). Also, make sure someone isn't calling [`jQuery.noConflict(true)`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) ..

Comment: it could be because of loading order. The fact that it works on another computer could be because of browser differences or machine speed. Could you show us the code where you load the scripts?

Comment: @user2246674  jQuery.noConflict(true) isn't being called; I did a search for it.

Comment: @Silvermind - this is what I have in the _Layout.cshtml:
   <script type="text/javascript">root = "@Url.Content("~/")";</script>
    <script src="@GlobalVariables.ResourceDomain/javascript/windows/lib.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

is that what you meant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't register the jQuery or jQuery UI in the Layout.cshtml file. You have to add reference to the jQuery library first and then reference to the jQuery UI library.
like here

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery.ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@GlobalVariables.ResourceDomain/javascript/windows/lib.js"></script>
```

Comment: Did this, but now I get a parser error message: An opening "(" is missing the corresponding closing ")", pointing to: 

<script type="text/javascript">root = "@Url.Content("~/)";</script>

Comment: what is `root`? try `var root='@Url.Content("~/")'` instead.

Comment: ok can you paste the code you are talking about(Layout.cshtml). then we can identify what is the actual error

Comment: Pasted. .. up above, as it wouldn't fit in the Comments section.

Comment: someone told me that the jquery library is not being included correctly, to also make sure there are no 404 errors .. . how can I check this?

Comment: Scripts folder: ~/Content/js

There we have the jquery-1.7.1.min.js, and jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js

Comment: Lets do this, comment all your script file references. and ad the above three lines with `src="/Content/js/jquery.min.js"` and respective other urls. then it should work without any issue. and then refer other files like above.

Comment: ..  I found a workaround .. .  if I use Google Chrome as the default browser, it flies right past that "error". .. so it appears that there's something in IE 8 that's triggering the error?
But Google Chrome will work for now until I determine if it's best to upgrade jQuery / use something else. Thank you so, so much for taking the time to help me!!